# OnTouch events on HorizontalScrollView - when control lost focus / user finger is out of control

Tags: c#, android, mono

I've got gallery with horizontal scroll view. When user is sliding scroll view I listen for OnTouch events and play animations etc.

Basically:

```
public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, Android.Views.MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Down");
            // Start Animation (change alpha imageviews in list to 100%)
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Move");
            // Do something...
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Up");
            // End Animation (change alpha imageviews in list to 50%)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But there is option that user start OnTouch event in control, but ends on moving his touch outside focused control. So action 'Up' won't run. Question is how to deal with that situation - I would like to know when that kind of situation will appear and programmatically call same code as in action 'Up'.

So event list looks like:

- 01-02 13:53:33.417 I/mono-stdout( 6759): OnTouch > Down
- 01-02 13:53:33.537 I/mono-stdout( 6759): OnTouch > Move
- 01-02 13:53:33.581 I/mono-stdout( 6759): OnTouch > Move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use `MotionEventActions.Cancel`:

```
public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, Android.Views.MotionEvent e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Down");
            // Start Animation (change alpha imageviews in list to 100%)
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Move");
            // Do something...
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Up");
            // End Animation (change alpha imageviews in list to 50%)
            break;
        case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
            System.Console.WriteLine("OnTouch > Cancel");
            // End Animation (change alpha imageviews in list to 50%)
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[public static final int ACTION_CANCEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL)

> Constant for getActionMasked(): The current gesture has been aborted.
>   You will not receive any more points in it. You should treat this as
>   an up event, but not perform any action that you normally would.